# Why Jsonpath does not return null if array of jsonArray is null?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonpath

I am having the below Json content.

```
{
    "aaaaaa": 
        {
            "id": 20956,
            "bbbbbb": [
            {"xxxxxxxx": []
            },
            {"xxxxxxxx": [1,2]
            }
              ]
        }
}
```

And the Json path is as below

```
$.aaaaaa.bbbbbb[*].xxxxxxxx[*]
```

instead of getting the result as [null,1,2] I am getting the result as [1,2]. How can I get the expecting result if there is null arrays?

I am obtaining the output as below.

```
output = JsonPath.read(jsonContent, jsonpath);
```

Comment: maybe because it's not null just a empty array

Comment: Yes, it should be correct. but I compared it with the xpath(with a XML file which has  same content as the json file). it is giving the expected output, if there are nulls. but the same thing I cannot do with the jsonPath